# Remove method doesn't remove any items from the DB. 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Let's see if I can make the step-by-step clear:

```
namespace InventoryManager.Controllers
{
    public class InventoryController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IInventoryRepository repository;

        //...

        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteItem(int id)
        {
            // Executes fine
            repository.Remove(id);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is executing the `Remove` method defined in `InventoryRepository`:

```
namespace InventoryManager.Models
{
    public class InventoryRepository : IInventoryRepository
    {
        private InventoryContext context;

        //...

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            InventoryItem item = context.Items.Find(id);

            // Executes fine
            context.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**But, I check my DB and no items are removed. Why is this?** There may be some information missing, so let me know what else you require.

I'm having issues debugging this because I'm out of my element. If you have methods of debugging this, or certain things/keywords I can look up to help solve my issue, I would be thankful.

Comment: are you sure you're ***committing*** those changes?

Comment: Err, committing those changes? How so?

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL or Entity framework ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're committing the changes you make to `Items` against your `DataContext`:

[**Linq to SQL:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx)

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```

[**Entity Framework:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx)

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Argh.. This is perfect. I owe you a beer. Is this commit required for any change to the DB using EF?

Comment: @Chase Yes, it is. I added a link to his Entity Framework header - check it out

Comment: yes, nothing is committed implicitly. due to the simple question of ***when to implicitly commit***. thus, the need to explicitly commit using `SubmitChanges` or `SaveChanges`

Comment: @TiesonT. Thanks for the link, it helps for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void Remove(int id)
        {
            InventoryItem item = context.Items.Find(id);
            context.Items.Remove(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: +1 That is the exact change I made. I'm not sure how I overlooked something so trivial. If you were a few minutes quicker, I would've accepted yours.